# K-Means min() function - value of index is static

Tags: matlab, octave

As the title mentions, my code is meant to iterate over every example in the training set, find the closest centroid and store it in the index 'idx'. Unfortunately, when I run my code, everything goes awry at the minimisation step. It returns the distance value just fine, but the index will repeatedly state "1" over every iteration. I'm pretty stumped right now, still trying, but stumped. Would appreciate feedback!

Here's my code for referral.

m = size(X,1);

```
distance = [zeros((size(X,1)),(size(K,2)))];
for i = 1:m
  Kxn_matrix = ones(K,1) * X(i,:);
  distance = sum((centroids - Kxn_matrix) ,2).^2;
  [i,midx] = min(distance,[],2);
endfor;
idx = midx;
```

Comment: You are changing loop variable i within the loop. Also, have you defined midx before?

Comment: Have you used either breakpoints or `keyboard` within the loop so you can pause/watch the values change? Best way to see what is happening is to watch it yourself.

Comment: You're only storing the *last* `midx` in `idx`. All of the others are lost.